# Enable litigation hold

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I would like to know if there is a way to enable/disable the `LitigationHold` attribute on an O365 mailbox with the Microsoft Graph API?

Currently the way I use is with PowerShell with below command

```
Set-Mailbox -LitigationHoldEnabled $true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported by Microsoft Graph. You can use Graph's [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) to add this suggestion.

As a general rule of thumb, Microsoft Graph surfaces APIs that mirror what a user would do while via a client application while PowerShell surfaces APIs that mirror what an Admin would do through the service's admin portal.

Answer (score 0):

This has been provided in Graph API Beta
POST /compliance/ediscovery/cases/{caseId}/legalHolds

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/ediscovery-case-post-legalholds?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=powershell

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31693341)